# How to append String content to array

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I already make the code but there's a problem. The compiler show me this message:

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
This is the code:

```
Dim array As List(Of String)
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        If Not row.IsNewRow Then
            array.Add(row.Cells(0).Value.ToString & "," & row.Cells(1).Value.ToString & _
                            row.Cells(2).Value.ToString & "," & row.Cells(3).Value.ToString)
        End If
    Next
```

The line with the problem is `array.add`

What's the problem?

Comment: You didn't instantiate the List.  Change `Dim array As List(Of String)` to `Dim array As New List(Of String)`.  Horrible variable name by the way...

Comment: Or try using Dim Array As New ArrayList(). Then use array.add()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use a list, you have to create an instance of it using `New`:

```
Dim array As New List(Of String)
```

Like Idle_Mind mentioned, it's a bad idea to use Array as a variable name. It's confusing and makes the code hard to read.